# relation between support of a measure and support of its marginal

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Support $\pi$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mu$ is its 1st marginal. **What is the relationship between the support of $\pi$ and the support of $\mu$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Pi$ denote the projection from $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, so $\mu=\Pi^*\pi$.  Then $\Pi(\operatorname{supp}(\pi))\subseteq\operatorname{supp}(\mu)$.  (As can be seen from the fact that $\operatorname{supp}(\mu)$ is the complement of the union of the open sets $O$ such that $\mu(O)=0$.  Since $\Pi$ is continuous, the inverse images $U=\Pi^{-1}(O)$ of those open sets are open, and hence the complement of $\operatorname{supp}(\pi)$ is at least as large as the union of those $U$, that is, of the complement of $\Pi^{-1}(\operatorname{supp}(\mu))$.)

But equality need not hold.  Let $r_n$ be an enumeration of the rationals  let $s_n = (r_n, n)$, let $S=\{s_n:n\in\mathbb N\}\subset \mathbb R^2$ and let $\pi = \sum_n 2^{-n} \delta_{s_n}$ be supported on $S$. It is easy to see that $S$ is closed (the points in $S$ are all at least distance 1 from each other) so $S=\operatorname{supp}(\pi)$.  So $\Pi(\operatorname{supp}(\pi)) = \mathbb Q $ but the support of $\mu$ is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: A simpler  example is to set $\mu$ to be uniform on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and let $\pi=(id,T)_\#\mu$, where $T(x)=\tan(x)$, so that the support of $\pi$ is the graph of tangent, while the support of $\mu$ is $[\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: thank you for your answer!

Comment: Hi! As a follow up question, i am wondering if  the closure of $\Pi(supp(\pi))$ is the same as the support of $\mu$. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know.  Both of our examples are of the form $\Pi$ of a closed set need not be closed, and I don't know if all counterexamples are of this form, either.  If anything comes to mind I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I think it's true and it can be easily proved by definition tracing.  Thanks though!